# ReactJS: JSON file is fetched from localhost instead of project directory

Tags: json, node.js, ajax, reactjs, npm

I have following directory structure of my project.

[image]

I have following code in my `index.js` file for loading `website.json` file.

index.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "../website.json",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       ContentType: 'application/json',
       success: function(data) {         
         this.setState({data: data});
         console.log(data);
       }.bind(this),
       error: function(jqXHR) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
       }.bind(this)
    })
  }
```

The problem is that I am using `npm start` command to server my react app from local directory of my application. This serves my app at `http://localhost:3000/` . Now the problem is that the application tries to load the `website.json` file from `http://localhost:3000/website.json` which gives a `404 not found` error.

So, my question is how my `website.json` file can be loaded from my project directory instead of localhost.

Note: my project folder is not at localhost but at virtual host.

**Update:** I am specifically asking why the ajax call is unable to load data from my project folder (I am using relative addressing) and instead including path from localhost. I want to load data using ajax call is it possible or not.

Comment: Show what you running as 'start'. You may find it in package.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver (I would guess Express) will be serving files from the 'public' folder.

For security reasons, web servers do not allow access to files outside of the directory root (/public in your case), so you will not be able to get the file by ajax (or from the browser).

If you really want to, you could either:

- Copy/Move the file into the public folder
- Create a symlink to the file in the public folder

Comment: @Nosyara has mentioned this below (not as clearly as above, however).

Comment: Thank @Alcinator you made me understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You may include it inside source as

```
var website = require('../website.json');
```

So it will be embedded during compile time.

Another way to do it - move `website.json` to public folder, than you may access it as  `ajax('/website.json'...`

Comment: Is it not possible by using ajax that is my question?

Comment: Yes, if you add API on back end. And than use relative URL to get the file by ajax.

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: You have to manage server side. Or move your file to public folder and ajax it from root.

Comment: Currently I am doing it on my local machine. For sure I will move it to server. So I want to simulate here at localhost. Later on i will be providing a different url at server side.

Comment: When you running it on local machine, you still using server, just it runs on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help also

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `ES6`/`ES2015` since you are using `react`. So instead of doing it in `componentDidMount` you can just add this at the top:

```
import websiteData from '../website.json';
```

And then you can just use `websiteData` as a variable in your component.

Comment: Yes it is possible by this method but my question is how to do it using a ajax call. I am updating the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Why do you need to do it via ajax? Is the json file changing? if not then doing it this way is perfectly suitable. If it is changing then `componentDidMount` would only load it once anyway.